# Populating tables in SQL Developer using data from a file

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a txt file containing a table with two columns student ID and GPA. I want to create a similar table in Oracle SQL developer. Is there some way to copy this data directly into SQL developer

Comment: you could write a block of code to do it using UTL_FILE.GET_LINE, see the following for an example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/System-Packages/UseUTLFILEtoreadfromafileandinsertintothelecturertable.htm

other option would be to use sqlldr, but this is outside of sql developer

Comment: Another completely out of the box solution is using **Text to DDL** in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and copy paste the DDL statements SQL Developer and execute as script. Make sure you remove all the double-quotation marks.

Comment: convert your txt file into `insert` script and run it in SQL Developer

Comment: Use an ETL tool like Informatica or SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple GUI method, you can connect to a db, right click on "Tables", "import data..." and use the Data Import Wizard.
Select the correct options (csv/delimited, tableName, cloumnsToImport...) and click "Finish".

Sorry, I cant post pics yet see the example screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7HFx.png

Answer (score 0):

You can create external table with that file, then copy the external table into a new internal table (usual table), here is a full example:

[External Tables Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) 
Then go to:

> Example: Creating and Loading an External Table Using ORACLE_LOADER